# local variable 'sentencia2' referenced before assignment

Tags: django

Me sale el error como lo podria solucionar?  Mi intencion es poder pasar el valor seleccionado y pasar la orden a la sentencia pero como podreis comprobar me sale error como debería hacerlo? Al parecer no se puede llamar
Codigo:

```
if request.method=="POST":
               select = request.POST['select']
               if select == 'div1':
            op= request.GET('op0')
            fecha_ini = request.POST['fecha_ini_0']
            fecha_fin = request.POST['fecha_fin_0']
            articulo = request.POST['articulo0']
            sentencia2 ="exec [PR].[dbo].[PR_PR]" + str(rec_sistrade) + "," + emp + "," + op + "," + fecha_ini + "," + fecha_fin
           elif select == 'div2':
            op= request.POST['op1']
            fecha_ini = request.POST['fecha_ini_1']
            fecha_fin = request.POST['fecha_fin_1']
            articulo = request.POST['articulo1']
            sentencia2 ="exec [Empresa].[dbo].[PT_GET_ORDENES_EVENTOS]" + str(rec_sistrade) + "," + emp + "," + op + "," + fecha_ini + "," + fecha_fin

  cr = cursor.execute(sentencia2)
  resultstable= namedtuplefetchall(cr)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es lo siguiente:

Para poder llegar a cursor.execute() requieres de sentencia2.
Para poder asignar algo a sentencia2 tienes que haber recibido mediante post 'select' y en caso de recibirlo que sea a fuerza 'div1' o 'div2' ya que de caso contrario sentencia2 no existe ni se asigna, una posible solucion es la siguiente:

```
sentencia2 = None # Inicializar sentencia2 para que no diga que se referencio antes de asignar

if request.method=="POST":
    select = request.POST.get('select', None) # Si viene select en el post guardar si valor, si no asignar None
    if select:
        if select == 'div1':
            op= request.GET('op0')
            fecha_ini = request.POST['fecha_ini_0']
            fecha_fin = request.POST['fecha_fin_0']
            articulo = request.POST['articulo0']
            sentencia2 ="exec [PR].[dbo].[PR_PR]" + str(rec_sistrade) + "," + emp + "," + op + "," + fecha_ini + "," + fecha_fin
        elif select == 'div2':
            op= request.POST['op1']
            fecha_ini = request.POST['fecha_ini_1']
            fecha_fin = request.POST['fecha_fin_1']
            articulo = request.POST['articulo1']
            sentencia2 ="exec [Empresa].[dbo].[PT_GET_ORDENES_EVENTOS]" + str(rec_sistrade) + "," + emp + "," + op + "," + fecha_ini + "," + fecha_fin
        

if sentencia2:
    # Validamos que sentencia2 exista para ejecutar
    cr = cursor.execute(sentencia2)
    resultstable= namedtuplefetchall(cr)
```